# Why mat-select doesn't execute ngModel value while a normal select does?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular2-ngmodel

I use angular material in my app, and therefore I use the `mat-form-field` `mat-select` and `mat-option` tag for select box.

I create a child component for that and add it in parent component. When I use:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select ...>
         <mat-option ...></option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and pass `ngModel` to parent it doesn't work as expected. No vlaue is being passed regarding two ways binding and `ngModel`

But when I use a normal/classic `select`:

`<select ...>
    <option ....></option>
</select>`

then it works straight forward.

Here is a [StackBlitz Demo with the complete code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnlue4?embed=1&file=src/app/data-list/data-list.component.html) for both cases.

Any idea what could be the issue for such strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is throwing an error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'Users'
```

I can't explain how the classic select is working, but the reason why the `MatSelect` doesn't work is indicated by that error - you aren't using `ngModel` properly in a form - you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` in `DataListComponent`. The `ControlValueAccessor` implementation is responsible for updating the form when the model changes - without it, model changes are not propagated back to the form.

It is possible that `MatSelect` (which doesn't use a select element) relies on something that the classic select doesn't, and because of that doesn't work the same way.

Comment: Yes, I see the error. I did fix it. the following was missing on the demo `ngDefaultControl`. The error has been removed now. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnlue4?embed=1&file=src/app/data-list/data-list.component.html)

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, but it encourage me to change my concept regarding custom form/select box. I changed it using `ControlValueAccessor` and it works fine. One more good reason to use `ControlValueAccessor` for the rest of the form elements.